# Difference/switch between big/small o in taylor series

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

for example i only know taylor series with small o

is there anyway to switch from small o to big o in taylor series and why when we want to see the nature of some series we use taylor series with big o instead of small o 
[image]
[image]